# Qt multi threading without using QThreadPool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a simple Qt application that should perform no more than three tasks at the same time. This should be done using threads in Qt without using `QThreadPool` or `QConcurrent`.

The application has two classes; a `Worker` class and a `ThreadManager` class. Included below is how my `Worker` class looks like. However, I need help on how to implement `ThreadManager`. This is the class that should ensure that no more than three threads are running at the same time; and it should also execute the `doWork()` slot of `Worker`.

The `QVector<QString>` that has to be manipulated by `Worker` is instantiated in the `MainWindow` class and there is no need to control how it's accessed because every task uses its own unique `QVector`.

```
//Worker class
class Worker : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
     void finished(QVector<QString>);

public slots:
     void doWork(QVector<QString> v);
};
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that the *right way of using threads* shouldn't involve `QThreadPool`? Qt has many threading technologies to choose from, and each one of them has its [use cases](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#choosing-an-appropriate-approach).

Comment: Too many uses of thread pool on the recent SO Qt page. :)

Comment: Maybe this is a homework assignment. However I would agree the "right way" depends on the use case.

Comment: Removed the confusion.

Comment: I read the description of your task. Use `QSemaphore` for controlling of jobs running. Limit the semaphore to 3 at the time: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsemaphore.html#QSemaphore and look at more details from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-semaphores-example.html It makes sense to make more threads than 3, of course.